# Can you get a Big Boss ranking on just the Tanker chapter?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty

In MGS 2, can you just do the Tanker chapter and get the Big Boss rank? If not, what is the highest rank you can get on it?

Answer (score -1):

That's a negative, Big Boss rank first appeared in MGS3 Snake Eater.

I think the ranks in the first two MG Solids are not leveled, meaning there's not one above the other, the ranks are given depending on common things during gameplay, like play time, people killed, etc. To my knowlege: **Orca** for killing a high number of people, **Pigeon** for a low/zero kill run, **Chetah** for low completion time, and so on. There are some, that I think include more than one feature, like if you kill a lot of people in a hurry, you get **Tarantula**.

I could be off about the Ranking requirements, but I have finished both MGS 1 & 2 more than 15 times each, and I'm sure you don't get Big Boss Rank.

Comment: This is incorrect. Big Boss rank in MS2 is extremely difficult to achieve (beat game under 3 hours on extreme, no radar/alerts/items/kills/rations) but is certainly doable.

Comment: My mistake, I've never seen it anywhere, do you have any evidence to support this?

Comment: Here's a full video of someone doing it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Gui9h5inLA

Comment: There's no "Big Boss" or any other Rank granted at the end of that _Hoaxed-Titled guide video_. Please verify

Comment: Per the [Metal Gear Speedrunners Wiki](https://metalgearspeedrunners.com/wiki/doku.php?id=big_boss_rank_requirements), Big Boss is apparently possible in MGS2. It requires Extreme or Eurpoean Extreme difficulty, a time of under 3 hours, 0 continues, 3 alerts, 0 kills, 0 rations, 0-8 saves, damage taken under 10 Lifebars, shots fired under 700, radar off. However, that seems like a full-game requirement, and I don't quite understand what the "on just the Tanker chapter" half of the question means in that context.

Comment: In the results screen on MGS2 it doesn't even appear the category "Shots Fired" or "Damage Taken". What version of the game are we talking about? I'm on PS2/PS3 HD Remaster US Version (Sonf of Liberty & Substance).
I'd be willing to try a run for it, if I thought it worthwhile, but I'm pretty sure that at some time I've met those requirements and more sure that a Big Boss Rank was not available in MGS2, since by the time the game was released, if you remember, Big Boss was still the villain in the story of the game. There was no Big Boss as we now know it